# jsonschema control property content regardless of property name

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to write a json-schema for the following json:

```
{
    "peopleByID": {
        "5534": {
            "name": "Bob",
            "weight": 82
        },
        "8423": {
            "name": "Donna",
            "weight": 73
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

The point is that I want to control the content of each property (required to contain name and weight), while not knowing in advance the property name (the person id). I couldn't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`additionalProperties` lets you set a schema that all properties (that weren't already covered by a `properties` or `patternProperties` keyword) must conform to:

```
"additionalProperties": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["name", "weight"]
}
```

[This is documented here.](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html)